# What is the right C# structure to deserialize this json into?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am getting json back from an http and I am trying to deserialized it into a C# object and it keeps coming back as null so my guess is that my data structure is off.  Here is my code:

```
    results = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;

    var restResponse = new RestSharp.RestResponse();
    restResponse.Content = results;
    var deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
    var page = _deserializer.Deserialize<Tree>(restResponse);
```

Here is the Json:

```
{
   "page":{
      "results":[
         {
            "id":"144111690",
            "type":"page",
            "status":"current",
            "title":"Title 1"
         },
         {
            "id":"157540319",
            "type":"page",
            "status":"current",
            "title":"Title 2"
         },
         {
            "id":"144082624",
            "type":"page",
            "status":"current",
            "title":"Title 3"
         }
      ],
      "start":0,
      "limit":25,
      "size":14
   }
}
```

and Here are my C# objects:

```
 public class Tree
{
    public Results page { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    public ResultDetails results { get; set; }
}

public class ResultDetails
{
    public List<PageInfo> Pages { get; set; }
}

public class PageInfo
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone advise on what is not "lining up" here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you directly create class structure by using Visual studio ..that will give you class structure matching with your json.

you can check here how to generate : [Visual Studio Generate Class From JSON or XML](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2015/07/introduction-below-article-is-on-one-of.html)

Copy you json >> visual studio Edit menu > Paste Special >> Paste Json as class

[image]

Comment: i never knew about that . . that is awesome

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
public class Tree
{
    public Page page { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int limit { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

`results` is an array in JSON, but you defined it as an object (`ResultDetails`)

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
public class Rootobject
{
    [JsonProperty("page")]
    public Page page { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public Result[] results { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("start")]
    public int start { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("limit")]
    public int limit { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("size")]
    public int size { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

And the implementation should be

```
results = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;

var restResponse = new RestSharp.RestResponse();
restResponse.Content = results;
var deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
var page = _deserializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(restResponse);
```